# How to disable AEC (audio echo cancellation) on Android 4.2?

Tags: settings, audio

For some of my experiments, I need AEC to be disabled.
Are there audio modes (loudspeaker, headset, bluetooth) when AEC is definitely disabled?

Are there any platform-specific options for MTK65xx chipsets?

Comment: 'sidetone' effect are available on MTK, but I don't think it affects AEC